# How to integrate $\large \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $\;\large \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}\;?\;$ Do I need to use u-substitution for $\,(1+x^2)\,$?

Comment: That’s certainly the easiest way: it makes the integral a very simple one.

Comment: It's much easier to judge whether an approach to a problem is useful *after* you have tried it out rather than *before*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the most straightforward way.

Let $u = 1 + x^2,\;$ then $du = 2x \,dx.\; $ Now you're all set to substitute:

$$\int \dfrac{2x\,dx}{1+x^2} \;\;=\; \;\int \dfrac{du}{u}\;\;=\;\; \ln |u| + C \;= \;\ln(1 + x^2) + C$$

---

***Added*** (to address comment below): 
Note that we can *omit* the "absolute value sign" surrounding $\,(1 + x^2)\,$ when substituting $\,u = 1+x^2\,$ in the final expression because we know that $\,(1 + x^2) > 0\,$ for all real $x$.

Comment: One small point, $u=|u|$ in this case. Otherwise we would have to write $ln|1+x^2|+C$

Comment: Note that $1 + x^2 >0$ for all values of x. That's the only reason I dropped them, as we are guaranteed that $|1 + x^2| = 1 + x^2$

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ You don't need any fancy technique. Look at an antiderivative table and try to work it out.

Scroll over the grey area for the solution.

> Note that $\displaystyle \int \frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx=\int \frac{(1+x^2)'}{1+x^2}dx=\log {\bigl(|1+x^2|\bigr)}=\log {(1+x^2)}$

Comment: The solution is not an integrand. You have the solution posted as an integrand. The point was to integrate the function to the left, which is the integrand.

Comment: @amWhy That was a funny mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$2x=(1+x^2)'$$

$$\int{\frac{(1+x^2)'}{(1+x^2)}}dx$$

Comment: Looks good now; +1.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln u(x) =\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)} $

in this case : $u(x)=x^2+1$ so the primitive is : $\ln(x^2+1)+C$